# How to implement Comet (long polling) in IBM Worklight?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

I need to implement long polling in IBM Worklight to get notifications of events happening on the server. Can anyone tell me how to do it with an Adapter procedure? Any code samples would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This blog post explains how to create a polling event source. https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/worklight/entry/configuring_a_polling_event_source_to_send_push_notifications?lang=en